# Testing uiRouter with requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I have been stuck on this issue for a bit and have not had success with any other questions on here regarding testing uiRouter with requirejs.  I have a fairly basic controller setup that uses the $state.go to transition between states once a button is clicked.

runsController.js

```
define([],
function() {
"use strict"
var runsController = function($scope, $window, $http, $state) {

    function getRuns() {
        $http.get($window.apiLinks.runs).success(function(data) {
            $scope.runs = data.objects;
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.error();
            console.error(data);
        });
    }
    getRuns();

    $scope.refresh = getRuns;



    $scope.createRun = function() {
        //$state.go('createRun');
    }

    return ["$scope", "$window", "$http", "$state", runsController];
});
```

The controller is added to an app that depends on uiRouter.

app.js

```
define(["angular", "js/controllers/runsController", "js/router", "uiRouter"],
function(angular, runsController, router) {
'use strict'

var appName = "myApp";
var app = angular.module(appName, ["ui.router"]);

app.config(router);

app.controller("runsController", runsController);


function getName() {
    return appName;
}

return {
    app : app,
    getName : getName
};

});
```

router.js

```
define(["./controllers/runsController"],
function(runsController){

var routes = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /runs
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/runs");

    // Set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('runs', {
            url: "/runs",
            templateUrl: "partials/runs.html",
            controller: "runsController"

        })
        .state('createRun', {
            url: "/createRun",
            templateUrl: "partials/runCreator.html"
        });
};


return ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", routes];

});
```

Here's the test I have setup for this controller:

```
define(["angular", "angularMocks", "js/app", "js/controllers/runsController"],
function(angular, mocks, app, runsController) {
'use strict'
describe('runsController Unit Tests', function() {
    var mockApp, scope, httpBackend, objects, state;


    objects = [
        {rid : 1, filename : "myFile.txt", exitCode : 0},
        {rid : 2, filename : "test.zip", exitCode : 0},
        {rid : 3, filename : "test2.tar", exitCode : 0}
    ];

    beforeEach(function() {

        mockApp = angular.module(app.getName());
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http, $state) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        window.apiLinks = {"runs" : "/mock/api/runs"};
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        state = $state;
        httpBackend.when("GET", "/mock/api/runs").respond({
            "objects"  : objects
        });
        $controller(runsController[4], {
            $scope : scope,
            $window : window,
            $http : $http,
            $state : $state
        });
        httpBackend.flush();
    }));

    it("Get state working in test environment", function() {

    });

    it("Test that controller automatically gets the runs", function() {
        // Because of the way our controller files are setup, we have to specify the
        // last element in the array instead of just
        expect(scope.runs.length).toBe(3);
    });


});
```

This is currently giving me an error message of: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state

From what I have been reading I believe this means I need to be injecting the dependencies that the controller needs in order to run state, but if I am using the app before every test I run then the dependencies should be in there when the .config() is done right?  Can anybody help me figure out what it is I am not seeing with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Have this issue been resolved?

Comment: There is a workaround you can use where instead of having $state as a parameter in your controller declaration, you can instead use $injector.get('$state').go('newState') and you will no longer get the test error.  I do not want to put that down as an official answer though because I do not think it is a good practice to call .go in that manner

Comment: I had this same issue and just solved it. Posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue this is what I came up with.

This is very important:

**karma.conf.js**

```
 {
    pattern: 'ROOT/TO/YOUR/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
    included: false
  },
```

**test-main.js** : This is your karma - require - config file

```
 paths: {
    // External libraries
    'angular': '/base/PATH/TO/YOUR/angular/angular',
    'angularMocks': '/base/PATH/TO/YOUR/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
    'uiRouter' : '/base/PATH/TO/YOUR/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router',
.....
```

- **/base/** + your path

### DO THE SHIMMY

```
 shim: {
    'angular': { 'exports': 'angular' },
    'angularMocks': { deps: ['angular'], 'exports': 'angular.mock' },
    'uiRouter' : {deps: ['angular'], 'exports' : 'uiRouter'},
```

#### Now we are inside out test.

define the module

```
define([
 'angular',
 'angularMocks',
 'uiRouter',
 .....
```

Now when you set up your **beforeEach**

```
BeforeEach(inject(function ($injector){
  $state = $injector.get('$state');
  ....
```

Hope this helps you out.